# Mocking BiFunction with Spock Java/Groovy

Tags: testing, groovy, mocking, java-11, spock

Trying to mock a function that returns a BiFunction unsuccessfully. 
The function looks like

```
public interface myInterface { 
  Optional<BiFunction<Object, Object, Object>> myAwesomeFunc()
}
```

Trying to mock like

```
def mockBiFunction = Mock(BiFunction)
mockMyInterface.myAwesomeFunc >> mockBiFunction 
mockBiFunction.apply(*_) >> mockReturnVal
```

This results in

```
No signature of method: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy49.apply() is applicable for argument types: (org.spockframework.lang.SpreadWildcard) values: [*_]
Possible solutions: apply(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object), any(), any(groovy.lang.Closure), every(), tap(groovy.lang.Closure), every(groovy.lang.Closure)
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy49.apply() is applicable for argument types: (org.spockframework.lang.SpreadWildcard) values: [*_]
Possible solutions: apply(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object), any(), any(groovy.lang.Closure), every(), tap(groovy.lang.Closure), every(groovy.lang.Closure)
```

Tried with

```
mockBiFunction(*_) >> mockReturnVal
```

That doesn't work either.

Edit:
Tried with

```
mockBiFunction.apply(object1, object2) >> mockReturnVal
```

This fails with

```
Cannot invoke method rightShift() on null object
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method rightShift() on null object
```

**When I have mocked it then why is it null ??**

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your interface method returns an `Optional`, not a `BiFunction`. More precisely, it returns `Optional<BiFunction<Object, Object, Object>>`. Therefore, your interface mock needs to return an `Optional` as well when stubbing `myAwesomeFunc()`. That is what IMO is wrong with your code.

Here is my take:

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q71602791

import spock.lang.Specification

import java.util.function.BiFunction

class BiFunctionMockTest extends Specification {
  def "mock BiFunction"() {
    given:
    def biFunction = Mock(BiFunction) {
      apply(*_) >> "dummy"
    }
    def myInterface = Mock(MyInterface) {
      myAwesomeFunc() >> Optional.of(biFunction)
    }
    def underTest = new MyInterfaceUser(myInterface: myInterface)

    expect:
    underTest.doSomething().get().apply("foo", "bar") == "dummy"
  }

  interface MyInterface {
    Optional<BiFunction<Object, Object, Object>> myAwesomeFunc()
  }

  static class MyInterfaceUser {
    MyInterface myInterface

    def doSomething() {
      myInterface.myAwesomeFunc()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment and answer. I will try and create a more MVCE question next time. Fully agree about how important that is. Cheers.

Comment: The best way to thank people on Stack Overflow is to accept and upvote correct answers or upvote helpful comments. Thanks for buying into the idea of using MCVEs in the future. Don't just try, simply do it. It is a basic developer skill. I know it costs time and effort, but the reward are correct and quick answers instead of wild speculations or educated guesses.

Comment: I would have definitely accepted your answer had I not been able to reach one on my own or if I am convinced yours is superior to mine. Again I understand the importance of MVCE and it's not about being lazy but sometimes you just don't have the luxury to create a MVCE out of working code just to ask a question. Most of the devs (including you) can figure out whats wrong with code snippets without having to run a MVCE in an IDE. I do thank you for trying and helping me still. I have edited my answer to include more details.  It was not about Optional that was the issue in my case.

Comment: I was glad to help you and spend some time on preparing an MCVE by myself, but now I am actually annoyed. Your updates answer now reproduces what I have posted first here. And you are contradicting yourself, because now you let the mock return an `Optional`, just like I suggested. You might have reached that conclusion before me, but your answer was simply wrong, and now you improved it to resemble mine. Mine is still clearly superior though, because it contains an MCVE, while yours still only contains snippets.

Comment: As for your sense of entitlement - being "too busy" to create an MCVE, but not too busy to ask and let others do the work for you - that excuse is just lame. Sorry, with all due respect, but this kind of reaction is what makes me wonder sometimes if answering questions of people like you is really worthwhile. Oh, and BTW: Without my own MCVE I would have been unable to answer your question. Do you really think I can just write an answer with two nested mocks and something as complex as an optional of a bi-function without implementing and running it first?

Comment: Like I said I'm thankful for you to answer and I cannot prove to you that I left the `Optional` out of my own answer the first time by mistake, so I will let you think what you want to. I just want to end by saying that there are a lot of people who could get help by seeing other answers and that was part of the intention of me posting here as I could not find something similar just by googling. I respect you for taking out time to answer other people queries but does that give you a right to judge them without knowing about them, hmmm not really I guess.

Comment: What is complex is really relative right.... a senior dev on my team can just see what I wrote the first time and tell what was wrong with my *not* MVCE question but I don't really want to fight it out. To each his own. One last time thank you for your efforts and hope you are not annoyed by helping others in the future.

Comment: Don't compare apples with oranges. Your colleague knows the code base and also saw your code in context, probably in your IDE. I just saw what meagre little snippets you published here, totally out of context. That is not the same! And one more time, I can see your edit history, and you added the details about the `Optional` only today, way after I did yesterday. Before that, neither in your question nor in your own answer was there any reference to `Optional` other than in the interface declaration itself. Therefore, your answer was plain wrong. Mine is correct.

Comment: I think I was not clear before - I meant my colleague can look into the code snippet & figure out what was wrong. But let's not go there. Also I said before when I answered my own question I forgot to add `Optional` to my own answer - probably since my issue was around wrongly mocking the `BiFunction` & that is why I agreed the first time that MVCEs are a good thing. I have never attempted to hide that fact by modifying my original answer to include `Optional` that is. What triggered me is the fact that people are quick to judge others & recommend basic developer skills without knowing context

Comment: I don't really have the bandwidth to fight it out with you if you don't want to believe. I wish you best of luck for your future. And one last time, thank you for your time.

Comment: Fine, whatever makes you happy. Now that we have established that you think your own answer was better, earlier, more complete, more comprehensive or whatever, I kindly suggest that you wrap up and self-accept it in order to avoid that other people looking for unaccepted questions find this one, only to find out that it has been answered and is off the table already.

Answer (score 0):

Ah looks like all I had to do was to use a function as the mock return value from the `BiFunction` so something like following works

```
def mockMyAwesomeFunc = abc -> mockReturnVal 
mockBiFunction.apply(object1, object2) >> mockMyAwesomeFunc
```

instead of doing

```
mockBiFunction.apply(object1, object2) >> mockReturnVal
```

Feeling really stupid now !!

Edit -- Updating the answer to more closely reflect the actual working code - this is what worked

```
def mockBiFunction = Mock(BiFunction)
mockMyInterface.myAwesomeFunc >> Optional.of(mergeBiFunction)
mergeBiFunction.apply(_, _) >> (a, b) -> {
    return mockValue
}
```